# Maintain share permissions migrating from Windows 2003 to Samba 3.5 or 4

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, samba

The title says it all. I'm interested in replacing a Windows file server with a Linux Samba file server, but the caveat is that share/folder permissions must be preserved. We'd be using the new active directory authentication in Samba, so the two servers would at least be in the same domain to make things a little simpler, and all the users/groups are domain-level users/groups. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: In my experience the long term cost of supporting the limitations/issues with Samba isn't worth the difference between it and a $600 version of Windows Server Standard which "just works".  Good luck.

Comment: @Bret I think I agree. We'll see if any answers change my mind.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short [manual](http://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_&_Active_Directory) direct from the Samba wiki. We have a same solution with a domain controller, LDAP and a seperate storage Server.

We use [GOSA](https://oss.gonicus.de/labs/gosa/) to to manage the AD.

The storage server has a replication from the active directory and with winbind you have the groups and users as local groups / users so you can set this to your folders and files.

With ACL on Linux you can set more and better permission to the folders. But i can say it's a long way with a lot of reading and testing. But the solutions works good.

At last you have to configure Samba shares for you folders that you want to share.

But a notice. When you have MAC clients you will get a lot of problems. In older MAC versions you have very strange problems that when you move files other files are deleted and many Samba problems are first fixed in OSX 10.6.

Answer (score 0):

Connect to both file servers with a Domain Admin level account. Then use xcopy with certain flags or RichCopy to transfer folders between the shares. I used to use xcopy until I switched to RickCopy with the latest transfer of nearly a terabyte of data in 12 million files.

[Xcopy Link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/240268)

[RichCopy link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithcombs/archive/2009/03/22/richcopy-bulk-file-copy-tool-released-get-it-here.aspx)